# Create/Read/Update & Delete views are not being generated

Tags: grails

I have a Race class and RaceController class. The Create/Read/Update & Delete views are not being generated when i run the app even thougn i have  "def scaffold = true" in the controller class. How can I generate the Create/Read/Update & Delete files

```
class Race {

    static hasMany = [registrations:Registration]


    String name
    Date startDate
    String city 
    String state 
    BigDecimal distance 
    BigDecimal cost 
    Integer maxRunners = 100000

    static constraints = {

        name()
        startDate()
        city()
        state()
        distance()
        cost()
        maxRunners()
    }

}

class RaceController {

    def scaffold = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grails generate-views some.package.DomainObject
```

will created the physical files

Answer (score 3):

That should be:

```
static scaffold = true
```

not

```
def scaffold = true
```